# Paypal Subscriptions/Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-ipn

I'm currently putting together a processing script for a website, and have run into a question that I can't seem to find a clear answer to. Paypal's documentation is iffy at best, and I do not use Paypal enough to discern the answer easily from the information they provide.

When a subscription is created through Paypal, they return two notifications in the first instance - subscr_payment, and subscr_signup.

My question is: Do future payments at the set data process as subscr_payment, or as recurring_payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future payments are sent as "subscr_payment"

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside